# how to send packet to subdomain

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I have two xmpp server instances: `mydomain.com` and `node1.mydomain.com`,
if I send a message from `user1@mydomain.com` to `user2@node1.mydomain.com` then
`mydomain.com` server thinks that `node1` is a so called component part of the jabber id
and doesn't send it.

How can I tell my xmpp server that I want to send message to the remote user?
Is there any possibility to do so in xmpp standard or it is only implementation dependent?

Comment: Sounds like an Openfire bug.  It should, if it doesn't serve this domain itself, look it up in DNS and try to establish s2s to it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is valid to make one server a subdomain of another.  I think you should rename the server to node2.mydomain.com.

Comment: The concept of "subdomain" doesn't exist in XMPP and does not imply any kind of relation.  The fact that it's common practice to have components as subdomains of the main host is just out of convenience.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is my xmpp server bug (I use Openfire), there is a patch fixing it [here](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/JM-1203).

The best practice for any xmpp server is to check if such component is registered, and if not to consider packet as being sent to a remote xmpp server.